# Having some trouble with my nVidia driver on kubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, 13.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I wanted to try out Linux again so I downloaded 13.10. I installed on my laptop which is a Dell XPS with two types of video cards, integrated Intel and a nVidia GTX555m. The way this laptop runs in Win 7 seems pretty straight forward. I install drivers for both cards. The intel card runs for most normal tasks, websurfing etc, but when I fire up a game or connect a 2nd monitor via HDMI then the nVidia card takes over and does the heavy lifting.

My problem is that in Ubuntu the intel drivers appear to be working normally but I cant seem to get the nVidia drivers to work/take over. When I launch Additional Drivers I see nVidia_331 as activated but not in use. In an effort to test the drivers I connected a 2nd monitor via HDMI but cant get the system to recognize it. Frankly I dont even know if this is a valid test or trigger to get the 555m to take over or not. I would like to get this to work before I spend more time getting Wine and play on linux installed only for them to fail because of video issues if possible.

My ultimate goal here is to be able to play Civilization V (steam install) and watch videos on netflix while browsing reddit!

I would appreciate any thoughts or advice you folks have! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia + Intel setup uses a technology called Optimus. Optimus support on Linux could be better, but it's generally working now.

To quote the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus):

> There are several method available:
>
> - disabling one of the devices in BIOS, which may result in improved battery life if the NVIDIA device is disabled, but may not be
>     available with all BIOSes and does not allow GPU switching
> - using the official Optimus support included with the proprietary NVIDIA driver, which offers the best NVIDIA performance but does not
>     allow GPU switching and can be more buggy than the open-source driver
> - using the PRIME functionality of the open-source nouveau driver, which allows GPU switching but offers poor performance compared to
>     the proprietary NVIDIA driver and does not currently implement any powersaving
> - using the third-party Bumblebee program to implement Optimus-like    functionality, which offers GPU switching and powersaving but requires extra configuration

Based on opinions I've heard, I would recommend [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

About Netflix... it is possible with [Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html#section_1_1).

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I will try the options you listed and see which one I can make work.